# Does a TVS diode provide adequate protection for an LCD screen powered from a car 12V outlet?

Tags: automotive, surge-protection, tvs, over-voltage-protection

I fitted an LCD screen in my car and I want to power it, along with other devices, directly from the car's battery. The other devices are specifically designed for automotive use, but the screen, a [10.1 inch LCD panel](http://e-sys.spb.ru/pdf/LP101WX2-SLP1-v0.1.pdf) paired to a [PCB800099](http://www.vslcd.com/Specification/VS-TY2662-V1.pdf) LCD controller board, isn't.

According to the specs, the PCB800099 can be powered from 12V. The seller said it can be powered anywhere from 5V to 24V, and indeed it actually came with a power cord with a USB on one end and a barrel jack on the other and it worked fine powered from a regular USB 2.0 port. So I connected it to the cigar lighter and ran the LCD screen during a 2 hour trip without any issues.

Even though it ran fine, I would like to prevent any failures in the long run due to voltage surges, load dumps, or other problems associated with its use in a car. Therefore, I'm thinking of adding a TVS diode in parallel with the screen:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxTi6W.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The LCD panel, according to its specs, has an input voltage range of 5V-21V for the LED backlight. I don't know if the LCD controller regulates the power for the backlight or if it simply acts as a passthrough. Because of that, I chose a TVS diode with a maximum breakdown voltage of 25.2V, or `1.2 x 21V`, to allow for some headroom. More specifically, the [1.5KE18CA-LF](https://www.tme.eu/Document/574f55cd54a0c134073ea930418e1e69/1_5KE_ser.pdf).

I've read suggestions for using a dedicated DC-DC regulator (googling for 12V output yields results for the more common 12V input and 5V output converters), simply ignoring this possible problem and hope for the best, just adding a varistor instead of the TVS, or more complicated circuitry which I'm not really keen on implementing.

My question is if this is enough to keep the screen alive and well in a car and is there anything else I should consider?

Comment: How much current does the screen draw? I'm wondering if a simple RC filter would be enough in conjunction with the TVS diode.

Comment: Don't know about the controller board, but the panel itself has a max current draw of 394mA, while the inrush current is 3.5A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backlight says it has a maximum rating of 21V, the LCD says 3.3V. It appears that the module has some kind of regulator to step down the voltage to 3.3V.

The diode will protect against events above ~17V as it starts to conduct at this point, however these TVS diodes work best against short transient events. The diode can take 60A of current, but only for a short duration. If the diode starts conducting during a long duration event, it can handle about 2W before it heats up enough to exceed it's max temp. Above 17V it would only take 100-200mA to cause a problem with heating the diode to exceed its max temp if it's heatsink is air. If you think the surge will exceed this then use more diodes or add a diode that can handle more current in parallel

Comment: But isn't the maximum voltage in a car supposed to be around 14V while the alternator is charging the battery and little to no load? Transients is what I want to protect against and I expected that these transients should exceed 22V. Is my expectation wrong?

Comment: @user1969903 Littelfuse have published an informative paper on the subject: [Suppression of Transients in an Automotive Environment](https://m.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics_technical/application_notes/varistors/littelfuse_suppression_of_transients_in_an_automotive_environment_application_note.pdf).